# Parse CDATA using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML and i want to extract only some data using using XSL

XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<RESULT>
<Response>
<StatusReport><![CDATA[FTPClientBeginSession finished successfully.
                    ServiceStartTime=[2016-12-05 09:24:04.382]
                    ServiceEndTime=[2016-12-05 09:24:04.497]
                    SessionToken=[Local_FTPClientAdapter_node1_14809478443821014:141891070]
                    ServiceTranscript=[
                     220 Server ready for new user.
                     > USER Partner123b
                     331 Password required for Partner123b.
                     > PASS *****
                     230 User Partner123b logged in.
                     ]
                     ]]>
      </StatusReport>
</Response>
</RESULT>
```

XSLT i am using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:template match="RESULT/Response/StatusReport/text()">
    <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and able to extract complete data in CDATA but i want only **ServiceTranscript** .
Is there is a way to extract only specific content from CDATA.

Comment: You'll need to use some string functions to extract the data you need. Are you able to use XSLT 2.0 (as in XSLT 2.0 you may be able to make use of regular expressions as a possible solution). Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing that when you say "you want only ServiceTranscript" you actually want everything from `ServiceTranscript=[` to the matching `]`. But I shouldn't have to guess - you should specify the precise requirement. And you haven't told us the rules: for example can the text between `[` and `]` contain any nested or escaped square brackets? What should happen if the closing square bracket is missing? etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks,i used <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,'ServiceTranscript=[')"/>